# Change connection string on button click for that specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, connection-string

I have a `LinkButton` in my `MasterPage` header:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkSwitchApp" runat="server" OnClick="LinkSwitchApp_Click">Switch To DataBase2</asp:LinkButton>
```

On click of that button I wanna change `connection string` for my application i.e. switch to `DataBase2` from `DataBase1`. Application by default is connected to DataBase1.

```
protected void LinkSwitchApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Code to connect to different connection string
 }
```

I have two `Connection Strings` in my `Web.Config` File:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=Server; Initial Catalog=DataBase1; Integrated Security=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="Second" connectionString="Data Source=Server; Initial Catalog=DataBase2; Integrated Security=true"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My application is connected to `DataBase1`(At Start), When user click on `LinkButton`(Text: Switch To DataBase2), The application lost connection with `DataBase1` and gets Connected to `DataBase2` and all the application data should be reloaded(even the data in controls like `GridView`, `Textbox`) from current `DataBase` i.e. `DataBase2`.

Now, The `LinkButton` Text will be changed to `Switch To DataBase1`, When user click on it again, then `DataBase1` will be connected and application will be  reloaded. But it will be only for that specific user other users should work on their choice of `DataBase`.

Currently, I am providing `connectionString` to my application(My DataBase Helper class) on `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` file. Like:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString;
       //Code to connect to Second ConnectionString(here or somewhere else based on condition)
    }
```

I am not creating sessions for users right now but willing to create if required. (I tried changing connection string dynamically in `web.config` but then it will change for all users that i don't want). Please help me to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance...!!!

Comment: Use `Session` variable. This is the easiest way.

Comment: @Alex Kudryashew Thanks, can you gave me idea for that i have never used session variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
//DbHelper class
public static string AppConnectionString(){
   if(Session["cnn"] != null)
     return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Second"].ConnectioonString;
   return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectioonString;
}

//button handler
protected void LinkSwitchApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if(Session["cnn"] != null)
     Session.Remove("cnn");
   else
     Session["cnn"] = true; //or whatever
 }

//any time you connect to DB
var conn = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(DbHelper.AppConnectionString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Option:

You can use [cookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) after that button was click

In your Button:

```
Protected void LinkButtonClick(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
     HttpCookie SetCookies = Request.Cookies["linkbutton"];
     SetCookies ["linkbutton"] = "Button was click";
     SetCookies .Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
     Response.Cookies.Add(SetCookies);
}
```

Then in every Module that you want to connect Database2,

Use

```
public string constr = String.Empty;
if(Request.Cookies["linkbutton"].ToString()=="Button was click")
{
     constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Second"].ToString()
}
else
{
      constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ToString()
}
```

Something like that.

Remember your cookies name must be the same.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, as i have no idea about cookies, Just wondering will it work for second time as well like when user wanna connect to second database second time

Comment: As far as i knew `Session` is not reliable when using like primary key as reference like you want to use session when user logged in with Session userid.. it will result a conflict when another user logged in. Just sharing my experience. Cookies is the best for me.. Coz it will stay in every individual computer and not in server. That's why i recommend to use cookies. Base on my own experience.

Comment: Just don't forget to make your cookies expires when user logged out.. You can read the reference above for better understanding in case my sample has a problem.

Comment: actually in my application i dont have any login page.